# wso2 esb - why is the activemq used for the JMS samples and not wso2 message broker?

Tags: wso2-esb

In the WSO2 ESB documentation, activeMQ is the default MQ for the samples.  I was just wondering why WSO2 Message Broker is not the default MQ for the samples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been basically a historical reason. When WSO2 ESB is released, there was no WSO2 Message Broker product. That product has been released recently. The documentation need to be updated and there is a public jira for this. Will be fixed with the next release of ESB in the future.

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DOCUMENTATION-86